# Will this non-manifold mesh of human head cause any problem in the future professional production?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, geometry, artifacts

[image]

I have just downloaded the head developed by the [Blender Studio](https://studio.blender.org/films/heist/gallery/?asset=6072). And surprisingly, I find that the head mesh is full of open holes. Ear holes, nose holes, eye holes and mouth hole are not closed.

[image]

[image]

Based on my past knowledge, the mouth bag, nose holes, and eye bags **are taught in class** to be closed.So this non-manifold mesh is challenging to what I learned in the class.

Will this non-manifold mesh cause any artifact in UV unwrapping, rendering, or animation please?

**Even if there is no artifact in the future production and it works perfectly, do companies or other professionals still require you to convert this non-manifold into a manifold mesh please?**

Comment: 3D printers will have problems with non-manifold meshes as far as my reading goes